# Clone PostgreSQL 11 from rsync

Tags: postgresql, repository, rsync

I try to clone the PostgreSQL repository on my servers to ensure some of them be able to update PostgreSQL components.
The reason is several of my servers are in specific network area, without Internet access.

For the version 8.x and 9.x it is possible by syncing this URL: rsync://yum.postgresql.org/pgrpm-94/redhat

I would like to do the same thing with URL like: rsync://yum.postgresql.org::11/redhat

Somebody know if is it possible, and which is the right URL?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the right URL (for example CeontOS 7):

rsync://rsync.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/11/redhat/rhel-7-x86_64/

Comment: it's a bit different now rsync.postgresql.org::pgsql-ftp/repos/yum/11/redhat/rhel-7-x86_64/